# A question on polynomials

Tags: polynomials

Let $D=\{0,1\}$.

Are there infinite values of $n\in \Bbb N$ for which there is a polynomial $p(x_1,x_2,\dots,x_n)\in \Bbb R[x_1,x_2,\dots,x_n]$ and a rational function $r(x_1,x_2,\dots,x_n)\in \Bbb R(x_1,x_2,\dots,x_n)$ of lower degree such that:
$p(x_1,x_2,\dots,x_n)|_{x_i\in D}=r(x_1,x_2,\dots,x_n)|_{x_i\in D}\in D?$

Comment: Of lower degree than what?

Comment: Turbo, by gutting your original question, you make it very difficult to see what the answer below (carefully prepared by Ilya Bogdanov) is exactly in response to.

Answer (score 5):

Still, such $p$ exists.

Let $Q=\{0,1\}^n$, and for every $q \in Q$ denote, as usual, $x^q=\prod_{i=1}^n x_i^{q_i}$. For every set of values $(a_q)_{q\in Q}$ there exists a unique multiaffine polynomial 
$$
  p(x)=\sum_{q\in Q} p_qx^q
$$ 
such that $p(q) = a_q$ for all $q\in Q$. This polynomial can be represented as
$$
  p(x)=\sum_{q\in Q}a_q\prod_{i\colon q_i=1}x_i\prod_{j\colon q_j=0}(1-x_j),
$$
as each summand attains $a_q$ at $q$ and attains $0$ at all other elements of $Q$. Therefore, the coefficient at $x_1\dots x_n$ is
$$
  p_{1,1,\dots,1}=\sum_{q\in Q}(-1)^{n-\sum_i q_i}a_q.
$$
So, if an odd number of $a_p$'s are ones, and the others are zeroes, then $p_{1,1,\dots,1}$ is odd and thus nonzero.

Having stated this, we now set $n=k^2$ for integer $k>1$ and rename the variables as $y_{ij}$ ($i,j=1,\dots,k$). Consider two polynomials $f$, $g$ of degree $k$ each:
$$
  f(y)=\sum_{i=1}^k\prod_{j=1}^k (1-y_{ij}), \\
  g(y)=\sum_{1\leq j_1,\dots,j_k\leq k}\prod_{i=1}^k y_{ij_i}.
$$
Then for every $y\in Q$, we have $f(y)\neq0$ if and only if $y_{i1}=\dots=y_{ik}=0$ for some $i$, and $g(y)\neq 0$ exactly if such $i$ does not exist. Thus means that the sets of zeroes of $f$ and $g$ on $Q$ are disjoint, and their union is $Q$. Thus, the function
$$
  r(y)=\frac{f(y)}{f(y)+g(y)}
$$
attains $0$ at all zeroes of $f$ on $Q$, and attains $1$ at all other points of $Q$.

Finally, I claim that the polynomial $p(y)$ reconstructed from $r(y)$ is of degree $n$. By the first paragraph, it suffices to show that $f$ has an odd number of zeroes on $Q$. Each such zero is a combination $(y_{ij})_{i,j=1}^k$ where for every $i=1,\dots,k$ we have $(y_{i1},\dots,y_{ik})\neq (0,\dots,0)$. So for each such string we have $2^k-1$ choices, and $f$ has $(2^k-1)^k$ zeroes, i.e. an odd number of them.

Comment: Oh, thousands excuses!!! Finally I realize that this misunderstanding was completely my fault. Sorry again... I'll try to fix it.

Comment: Sorry for this again, I was not only too silly but also too snobby. I have deleted my silly comments. Now I hope that I've typed the solution for the real question.

Comment: Oh dear! I was confused by $\{0,1\}$ instead of $\{-1,1\}$. This is not really a Fourier transform, it is some its analogue, and the formulas are a bit different. Nevertheless, the key fact is still true, I've replaced this fragment by an explicit computation of $p_{1,1,\dots,1}$. Sorry again.

Comment: I guessed. But, in fact, you don't need the inclusion--exclusion formula, see edit.

Comment: I don't think so (still I am not sure). In fact, the existence of such function $k(x)$ is equivalent to existence of two polynomials $f$, $g$ of degree $k$ such that the disjoint union of their roots on $Q$ is $Q$, AND the set of zeroes of (say) $f$ is good enough (we need exactly $p_{1,\dots,1}$ not to vanish). I have no ides  how to construct such polynomials of lesser degree.

Comment: I want to delete this question. I am unable to delete since it has answer. Do you think you could remove the answer? Thank you very much.

Comment: The answer puts good mathematical content on this website, Turbo. I don't think it should be deleted; if it is deleted, I'll vote to undelete.